# Is there a way to combine $(document).ready and $(window).resize together so they call only 1 function?

Tags: jquery, html, function, resize, document-ready

i have the following code below and somehow everytime i run the file, the $(document).ready will call the    showViewportSize(); and will print 1 set of 10 video. Next,  when the window resize although my video are printed out with the new resize size, it print another set of 10 videos after the first set. It is  not overwriting the videos produce from the$(document).ready!!  Could anyone please help me on how should i re-edit this so that when the document load, the video will print and when is resize, the video will resize dynamically but not print another time when is resize.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="mediaelement-and-player.min.js"></script>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0"/>
</head>


<body>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<div id="videoHolder"></div>
<script  type="text/javascript">

 window.oncontextmenu = function() {
    return false;
  };

if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();

    }
  else {// code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }


    xmlhttp.open("GET","amk6.xml",false);
    xmlhttp.send();
    xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML;


var videoheight = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("height");
var videowidth = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("width");
var numcameras=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("CameraCount");
var vidht =  videoheight[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue ;
var vidwh =  videowidth[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue ;
var numCam = numcameras[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
var cameraID = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("CameraID");
var title = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("title");
var type = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("type");
var vidtype = type[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
<!-- document.write('<h2>vidheight:</h2>'+ vidht);
<!-- document.write('<h2>vidwidth:</h2>'+ vidwh); -->
<!-- document.write('<h2>numCam:</h2>'+ numCam); -->
 -->
var scrht;
var scrwh;
var rscale;
var numCols;
var numRows;
var numCells;
var boxht;
var boxwh;


$(document).ready(function(e) {
   showViewportSize();
});
$(window).resize(function(e) {
   showViewportSize();
});
function showViewportSize() {
   scrwh = $(window).width();
   scrht = $(window).height();
     rscale = 1.0;
     numCols = Math.floor(scrwh/(rscale*vidwh));
     numRows = Math.floor(scrht/(rscale*vidht));
     numCells = numRows * numCols;
     while((numCells < numCam)&(rscale > 0.1)){
       rscale -= 0.02;
         numCols = Math.floor(scrwh/(rscale*vidwh));
         numRows = Math.floor(scrht/(rscale*vidht));
         numCells = numRows * numCols;
     }
     if (numCells >= numCam)
     {
            boxwh = Math.floor(rscale*vidwh);
            boxht = Math.floor(rscale*vidht);
        }
        else
        {
            boxwh = vidwh;
            boxht = vidht;
        }
for(i=0;i<=cameraID.length;i++) {

    var CamID =  cameraID[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue ;

    $('#videoHolder').append('<video height="' + boxht + '"' + 'width="' + boxwh + '"'  
    + 'title="' + CamID + '"' + 'autoplay loop ><source src="' + CamID + '.'
     + vidtype + '"' + 'type="video/' + vidtype + '"></source></video>');
}


   $('#width').text(scrwh);
   $('#height').text(scrht);
     $('#scale').text(rscale);
     $('#rows').text(numRows);
     $('#cols').text(numCols);
     $('#boxwidth').text(boxwh);
     $('#boxheight').text(boxht);



}


</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. You can bind it to both the load and resize (or ready) event in same line as below:

```
$(window).on('load resize', function () {
// your code
});
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Just change

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
   showViewportSize();
});
$(window).resize(function(e) {
   showViewportSize();
});
```

to

```
$(document).ready(showViewportSize);
$(window).resize(showViewportSize);
```

The way you originally did it defined two separate anonymous functions which both call `showViewportSize()`. The way I changed it to calls `showViewportSize` directly, and will pass in the `event` object as a first parameter.

Comment: Hi bro! i tried, but the video keep printing appending whenever is resize. For example, when the document load, it print the video 1 time. when the window resize, it keep print another time. why is this happening??

Comment: because thats what the function does. it sounds like you need one function that loads and prints, and one that just prints. so refactor this into 2 functions: one that just prints, and one that loads and CALLS the one that prints.

Comment: is it like this??                                                                                                        function showVideo() {
    showViewportSize();
 for (var a=0; a<cameraID.length; a++){
 var cam = cameraID[a].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
 $('#videoHolder').append('<video height="' + boxht + '"' + 'width="' + boxwh + '"'  
  + 'title="' + cam + '"' + 'autoplay loop ><source src="' + cam + '.'
   + vidtype + '"' + 'type="video/' + vidtype + '"></source></video>'); 
  


}
}



$(document).ready(showVideo);
$(window).resize(showVideo);